# Java RegEx doesn't find

Tags: java, regex

Cant understand why this RegEx doesn't find text

```
Pattern patternPairOfAddOrSub = Pattern.compile("(/A|[^*/])(-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)([+|-])(\\d+\\.?\\d*)(/Z|[^*/])");
Matcher matcher = patternPairOfAddOrSub.matcher("2+4+5");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

On this site https://regex101.com/ the same pattern (with adaptation of course) found this without troubles, can someone say me why?

Comment: How did you write it on the site?

Comment: (\A|[^*\/])(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+|-])(\d+\.?\d*)(\Z|[^*\/]) @YassinHajaj

Comment: @YassinHajaj , so can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `(/A|[^*/])(-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)([+|-])(\\d+\\.?\\d*)(/Z|[^*/])` pattern to the following one `(/A|[^*/])?(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+|-])(\d+\.?\d*)(/Z|[^*/])?`.

Following your pattern, you have to put at the beginning or end of the line an one of the next characters: `+`, `^`, `*`, `/`.

Comment: yes, it founds, but also it finds "2-3" in "2-3/5", thats wrong in my logic.

Comment: @ДаниилПопереков, what is your logic?

Comment: i need to add or substuct the pair of numbers if only the previous or next symbol not * and not /  (or its first or last number) @AndrewTobilko

Comment: @ДаниилПопереков, `"[+^*/](-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)[+|-](\\d+\\.?\\d*)[+^*/]"` -> `"2-3/5"` -> `false`